# Behat / Selenium - Element is visible but not visible for testing framework

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, behat, gherkin

I am not sure is it Behat or Selenium issue, but on Google's account page where user can manage and remove connected to account apps - I can not actually delete one with Behat, because it thinks that elements in dialog confirming removing are invisible.

The page is here: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

If you have any connected to your google account app (like Quora or anything else) click `Remove` you will see confirmation dialog, it has button `OK` in it, I can select this element with Behat, but `$el->isVisible()` returns `false`.

Do not know what to do. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not say why it is `invisible` but you can just go ahead and click it with `JavaScript`, like this:

```
    $cssSelector = "div[role='dialog'] div[role='button'][autofocus] SPAN";

    $js  = 'var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");';
    $js .= 'var element = document.querySelectorAll("'.$cssSelector.'")[0];';
    $js .= 'event.initEvent("click", true, true);';
    $js .= 'event.eventName = "click";';
    $js .= 'element.dispatchEvent(event);';

    $this->getSession()->executeScript($js);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK is not a button, but:

```
<content class="Nb"><span>OK</span></content>
```

So you cannot select it with "press "OK"". If you have a proper selector, you may wait for button to appear (I gue), or use:

```
$this->getSession()->wait($time, '<javascript condition>');
```

inside your context class.

Hope this helps.